# Table of SSBB Character Opponent Strengths and Weaknesses?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I am looking for a comprehensive table or article on each brawl character's opponents they are strong against (Strengths) and opponents they are weak against.

For a given character give me other characters he/she is strong against and weak against.

It seems like this type of analysis should be easy to find and relatively easy to create if one knows the game inside and out. I also feel that it would be beneficial to the community to have such a table indexed and referenced.

Comment: Given the fact that the developers try their best to balance each character out, I don't think it's going to be easy to make such a character sheet. But I don't really know the game inside and out, so my opinion really doesn't count.

Comment: As @Nolonar said, the game doesn't really work like that. No characters are really objectively better or worse against others. The answer for this question would have to be completely based on opinion.

Comment: Except its a competitive game and there actually is a competitive agreed tier system and matchup ratings. Overall pro player agreement is generally accepted as a valid source on this site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSBB character match-up graph is availble [on the wiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Character_matchup_%28SSBB%29). Obviously this doesn't include an explanation on that particular page, but you can view the character pages to get an explanation of each match-up for the most part. The list is sorted by tier list. Interesting how the only notably unusual match-up that deviates very strongly from the tierlist is fox v shiek.
[image: matchup graph]

Comment: Well, hit me over the head with a fish and call me Barbara. Apparently there is a good answer for this.

Comment: You might want to mention, that in this chart Meta Knight is strong against almost all characters. You know, just in case the link ever died and people were wondering how they should read the chart.

Comment: Anyone who has played SSBB knows how broken metaknight is, haha.